# How do I use regular expression to list words that start with vowels in a sentence

Tags: python, regex, algorithm

So say, I have a sentence as follows:

```
sent = "My name is xyz and I got my name from my parents. My email address is nomail@gmail.com"
```

I want to get all the words in this sentence that start with a vowel, so words like **is**, **I**, **is**. This is my regular expression so far and it isn't working.

```
re.findall('^(aeiou|AEIOU)[\w|\s].',sent)
```

This is the result I get

```
['. ', '..', '.s', '@g', '.c']
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your parentheses are not balanced, and you are not checking for word boundaries. Try this:

```
"\b[(aeiou|AEIOU)].*?\b"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.findall` with `re.I`:

```
import re
sent = "My name is xyz and I got my name from my parents. My email address is nomail@gmail.com"
result = re.findall('(?<=\W)[aeiou]\w+|(?<=\W)[aeiou]', sent, re.I)
```

Output:

```
['is', 'and', 'I', 'email', 'address', 'is']
```